# Customized Alert box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I am trying to make customized javascript alert boxes. I  found this code which is working fine but I dont know how exactly it is working:

## The Javascript is:

```
function CustomAlert() {
  this.render = function(dialog) {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (350 * .5) + "px";
    dialogbox.style.top = (winH / 2) - (350 * .5) + "px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Alert!";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
    document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button id="ok" onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
};
  this.ok = function() {
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
  };
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

## The Stylesheet is:

```
#dialogoverlay{ 
display: none; 
opacity: .8; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
background: #ccc;
width: 100%; 
z-index: 10; 
}
#dialogbox{
display: none; 
position: fixed; 
background: #333; 
width:350px; 
margin: 10px auto;
z-index: 10; 
border: 5px solid #1ad;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 }

#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{
background: #111; 
font-size:19px;
padding:10px; 
color:#CCC;
border: 5px solid #111;
border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ 
background:#333; 
padding:20px; 
color:#FFF; 
text-align: center;
border: 5px solid #333;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
} 
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ 
background: #333;
padding:10px; 
padding-right: 30px;
text-align:right; 
border: 5px solid #333;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
}
#ok{
padding-bottom: 2px;
background: url(images/goldbutton.png);
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
width: 62px;
height: 30px;
border: none;
font-size: 12px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

And

## HTML is:

```
 <div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
    <div id="dialogbox">
        <div> 
            <div id="dialogboxhead"></div> 
            <div id="dialogboxbody"></div> 
            <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <button onclick="alert('You look very ordinary today.')">Default Alert</button> 
    <button onclick="Alert.render('You look very pretty today.')">Custom Alert</button>

    </div>
```

All of it working fine. But I dont wnat to call this popup function from my HTML code but from another javascript file.
I am facing problem when I am trying call this render() function from another javascript function.

```
 function pop(){
    // code to call 
    // the render function
 }
```

Comment: can you show your code where you use the .render() function?

Comment: What kind of a problem do you have? Did you try calling `Alert.render('You look very pretty today.')` from your function, and if yes, what was the result?

Comment: As of now I am calling render function onclick event of a button in the HTML code(I have shared it). But I want to call this from another js file.

Comment: Also why do you "find" some code around, instead of sticking with the standards ? (jQuery or other stable products) ?

Comment: @Zemljoradnik Yes I have written the same. It didnot work. Warning issued was Alert global variable is not defined. Then included the js file where whole function is written It didnot work after that also.

Comment: @Sushovan, `Alert global variable is not defined` since it is located in the .js file for the function.. if you want to run it in another .js file, make sure that the .js file that has the function is included and you declare the `var Alert = new CustomAlert();` in your new file

Comment: That probably means that you either haven't included the `Alert` file in your HTML, or you have included it after the file where your `pop` function is.

Comment: @catzilla : Yes tried that but of no use..

Comment: @Zemljoradnik: I have included inside head tag.

Comment: Than you will have to show us all of the relevant code here. Can you make a snippet?

Comment: Dont know where the problem was but it started working.. Anyway thanks a lot guys...